# flocker plugin not found, error response from daemon

Tags: linux, plugins, docker

Got the following error while using `flocker`, can any body help? I'm using `CentOS7`.

```
[root@agentNode ~]# docker run -v apples:/data --volume-driver flocker busybox sh -c "echo hello > /data/file.txt"
docker: Error response from daemon: create apples: create apples: Error looking up volume plugin flocker: plugin not found.
See '/usr/bin/docker-current run --help'.

[root@testnode7 ~]# docker run -ti -v volumename:/data --volume-driver=flocker busybox sh
docker: Error response from daemon: create volumename: create volumename: Error looking up volume plugin flocker: plugin not found.
See '/usr/bin/docker-current run --help'.
```

Comment: Kindly, read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking your next question.

Answer (score 0):

kindly run docker -v and share the result, i suspect something changed in latest docker release 1.12, also share your flocker service logs
`cat /var/log/flocker/flocker-docker-plugin.log`

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the same problem here.

```
[root@manager1 vagrant]# docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.12.2
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   bb80604
 Built:
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.12.2
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   bb80604
 Built:
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

check if clusterhq-flocker-docker-plugin installed

```
[root@manager1 vagrant]# yum install clusterhq-flocker-docker-plugin
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.ventraip.net.au
 * epel: mirror.overthewire.com.au
 * extras: centos.mirror.serversaustralia.com.au
 * updates: centos.mirror.serversaustralia.com.au
Package clusterhq-flocker-docker-plugin-1.15.0-1.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

ok check status flocker-dataset-agent

```
[root@manager1 vagrant]# systemctl status flocker-dataset-agent
● flocker-dataset-agent.service - Flocker Dataset Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/flocker-dataset-agent.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2016-10-14 02:57:41 BST; 1s ago
 Main PID: 16908 (flocker-dataset)
   Memory: 33.7M
   CGroup: /system.slice/flocker-dataset-agent.service
           └─16908 /opt/flocker/bin/python /usr/sbin/flocker-dataset-agent --journald

Oct 14 02:57:41 manager1 systemd[1]: flocker-dataset-agent.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Oct 14 02:57:41 manager1 systemd[1]: Started Flocker Dataset Agent.
Oct 14 02:57:41 manager1 systemd[1]: Starting Flocker Dataset Agent...
```

ok check status flocker-container-agent

```
[root@manager1 vagrant]# systemctl status flocker-container-agent
● flocker-container-agent.service - Flocker Container Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/flocker-container-agent.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2016-10-14 02:57:56 BST; 760ms ago
 Main PID: 17032 (flocker-contain)
   Memory: 23.2M
   CGroup: /system.slice/flocker-container-agent.service
           └─17032 /opt/flocker/bin/python /usr/sbin/flocker-container-agent --journald

Oct 14 02:57:56 manager1 systemd[1]: Started Flocker Container Agent.
Oct 14 02:57:56 manager1 systemd[1]: Starting Flocker Container Agent...
```

check status flocker-docker-plugin

```
[root@manager1 vagrant]# systemctl status flocker-docker-plugin
● flocker-docker-plugin.service - Flocker Docker Plugin
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/flocker-docker-plugin.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

enable and restart

```
[root@manager1 vagrant]# systemctl enable flocker-docker-plugin
Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/flocker-docker-plugin.service to /usr/lib/systemd/system/flocker-docker-plugin.service.

[root@manager1 vagrant]# systemctl restart flocker-docker-plugin

[root@manager1 vagrant]# systemctl status flocker-docker-plugin
● flocker-docker-plugin.service - Flocker Docker Plugin
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/flocker-docker-plugin.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2016-10-14 02:59:40 BST; 1s ago
 Main PID: 17973 (flocker-docker-)
   Memory: 43.9M
   CGroup: /system.slice/flocker-docker-plugin.service
           └─17973 /opt/flocker/bin/python /usr/sbin/flocker-docker-plugin --journald

Oct 14 02:59:40 manager1 systemd[1]: flocker-docker-plugin.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Oct 14 02:59:40 manager1 systemd[1]: Started Flocker Docker Plugin.
Oct 14 02:59:40 manager1 systemd[1]: Starting Flocker Docker Plugin...
```

OK try again

```
[root@manager1 vagrant]# docker volume create --name persistent-vol-11 -d flocker
Error response from daemon: create persistent-vol-11: create persistent-vol-11: Error looking up volume plugin flocker: plugin not found
```

try using the plugin with docker run

```
[root@manager1 vagrant]# docker run -v apples:/data --volume-driver flocker busybox sh -c "echo hello > /data/file.txt"
Unable to find image 'busybox:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/busybox
56bec22e3559: Pull complete
Digest:     sha256:29f5d56d12684887bdfa50dcd29fc31eea4aaf4ad3bec43daf19026a7ce69912
Status: Downloaded newer image for busybox:latest
docker: Error response from daemon: create apples: create apples: Error looking up volume plugin flocker: plugin not found.
```